# Disable regex searching in specific windows

Tags: regular-expression, gvim, vim-windows

I usually have about 4 or 5 windows open in Vim. Currently - one of my files is very large(in size) - a CPU cache trace. Every time I search with "/", vim searches all windows before returning the result which takes a very long time because vim tries to search the CPU trace. Is there any nifty feature to just have vim search my current window?

Comment: I know huge files can generally slow things down but seems strange that it's just search. Do you have `hlsearch` enabled? If so see if `:set nohlsearch` makes a difference. Otherwise, try vim with bare configuration `vim -u NONE file ...`. Does that make much difference? (I'm mostly spitballing here...I'm a bit surprised by this...though admittedly I don't know much about search implementation.)